# Presenting UIViewController from programmed button issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

I have a `UIScrollView`, with a button I created in my `UIViewController` that presents another view controller, but when I run it, it gives me an error that it cannot find storyboard name "AddVC" though my VC is named in the storyboard id "`AddVC`" I do have some pictures, so please take a look at it.

here is the compiler:

[image: http://imgur.com/l0djhHA]

here is the code: Button on top with action, with also part of a button on the bottom, ignore middle (sorry for large photo):

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Vs5MT]
And the storyboard:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/A1COC]

Please look at the images to help tell me what I am messing up, it is probably a simple fix.

Thanks - Randy

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Please [edit] your question and copy and paste relevant code into your question (and be sure you format it properly).

Comment: You have add wrong name of your storyboard replace it with `Main`: `UIStoryboard(named: "Main", bundle: nil)`

Comment: Bhavin Ramani, just post that answer, i feel really dumb, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have give wrong name of your storyboard. Replace the name with your actual `storyboard` name:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AddVC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually for storyboard name you have given storyboard ID.
Try giving

```
let VC = UIStoryboard(name:<storyboard name>, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"AddVC")
```